solana/web.js npm is runs only in typescript or not
i have installed @solana/web3.js at this specific version 2.0.0-preview.3.20240607030342.abbdc5b1d373cb555b1aab6d450854939407a8ab in react js,but it's ask typescript package.
my question was this solana.web3.js is runs only in typescript or not.

@solana/web3.js can be used in both JavaScript and TypeScript projects, and TypeScript is not required to run it in a JavaScript-based project.
